# In Ckeditor how to copy/get all formatting from a selected text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor ver.3.6 in my Asp.net MVC 3 Application.

My requirement is to create Paint format option in the Google doc.I need to implement Paint format option in a ckeditor.

In Ckeditor how to copy/get all formatting such as  font, font effects, centered paragraph alignment from a selected text(source) to a  newly selected text (destination).

Please suggest a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to replace the content of a selected html with the text in one field. On a button click, call this function:

```
function Replace()
 {  
     var sel = editor.getSelection();   
     var ele=sel.getStartElement();
     if(ele.hasAttributes())
     {
        var insertele= editor.document.createElement('span');
        ele.copyAttributes(insertele,{type:1,value:1})
        insertele.setHtml($("#repTxt").val());
        editor.insertElement(insertele);        
     }  

 }
```